# Show all methods of a function in Julia

Tags: julia

How can I show **all** the **methods of a function** in Julia (**multiple dispatch**)?

For example, all the methods that exist in the namespace for the function `abs`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [`methods`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.methods) function will return the [method table](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/functions/#Method-Tables-1) for the given function:

```
julia> methods(abs)
# 13 methods for generic function "abs":
[1] abs(a::Pkg.Resolve.FieldValue) in Pkg.Resolve at /home/david/pkg/julia-bin/julia-1.4.0-rc1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Resolve/fieldvalues.jl:61
[2] abs(a::Pkg.Resolve.VersionWeight) in Pkg.Resolve at /home/david/pkg/julia-bin/julia-1.4.0-rc1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Pkg/src/Resolve/versionweights.jl:36
[3] abs(::Missing) in Base at missing.jl:100
[4] abs(x::Float64) in Base at float.jl:528
...
```

As of Julia 1.4, you can filter the method table by module. For example, listing the methods of `abs` which were defined in the `Dates` module:

```
julia> methods(abs, Dates)
# 1 method for generic function "abs":
[1] abs(a::T) where T<:Dates.Period in Dates at /home/david/pkg/julia-bin/julia-1.4.0-rc1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/Dates/src/periods.jl:95
```