# How does the methods function work in Julia?

Tags: julia

The [methods](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.methods) function returns the [method table](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/functions/#Method-Tables-1) of a function as also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694318/show-all-methods-of-a-function-in-julia). I am looking for an explanation on how the function works.

Consider the following example in Julia 1.7:

```
julia> f(a::Int64,b::Int64=1,c::Float64=1.0) = (a+b+c)
f (generic function with 3 methods)

julia> g(a::Int64,b::Int64=1;c::Float64=1.0) = (a+b+c)
g (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> methods(f)
# 3 methods for generic function "f":
[1] f(a::Int64) in Main at REPL[1]:1
[2] f(a::Int64, b::Int64) in Main at REPL[1]:1
[3] f(a::Int64, b::Int64, c::Float64) in Main at REPL[1]:1

julia> methods(g)
# 2 methods for generic function "g":
[1] g(a::Int64) in Main at REPL[1]:1
[2] g(a::Int64, b::Int64; c) in Main at REPL[1]:1

julia> f(1,1.0)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Int64, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  f(::Int64) at REPL[1]:1
  f(::Int64, ::Int64) at REPL[1]:1
  f(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float64) at REPL[1]:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[4]:1

julia> g(1,c=1.0)
3.0

julia>
```

It is not quite clear to me why there is no method `f(::Int64, ::Float64)` (hence the error). I am also wondering why there is no error for `g(1,c=1.0)` given that `g(::Int64, ::Float64)` or `g(::Int64, c)` are not listed as valid methods for `g`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, so to be a bit technical this is really more accurately a question about how type annotations, dispatch, optional arguments, and keyword arguments work in Julia; the `methods` function just gives you some insight into that process, but it's not the `methods` function that makes those decisions. To answer your individual questions

> It is not quite clear to me why there is no method `f(::Int64, ::Float64)` (hence the error).

There is no method for this because you you can only omit optional normal (non-keyword) arguments contiguously from the last normal (non-keyword) argument. Consider the following case:

```
julia> f(a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1) = a + 2b +3c +4d
f (generic function with 8 methods)

julia> f(2,4)
```

If there were not a rule for this, the compiler would have no idea whether the `2` and `4` provided were supposed to be for `a` and `b`, or do I mean that actually I wanted the `2` to go to `a` and the `4` to go to `d`? or `c`? Or anything! This would be undecidable. So we have a rule, and the rule is that the first argument goes to `a`, the second to `b`, and the omitted ones are `c` and `d`. Even though you have specified defaults, you cannot omit middle arguments, you can only omit the last N optional arguments. This is just the rule, and it does not matter whether or not you have applied type annotations or not.

> I am also wondering why there is no error for `g(1,c=1.0)` given that `g(::Int64, ::Float64)` or `g(::Int64, c)` are not listed as valid methods for g.

Firstly, there is no method for `g(::Int64, ::Float64)` or `g(::Int64, c)` because keyword arguments (in this example, `c`) do not participate in dispatch. There is no error for `g(1,c=1.0)` because when you write `g(1,c=1.0)`, you the optional argument for `b` is falling back to its default, so you are actually calling `g(1,1,c=1.0)` When you write `g(1,c=1.0)`, you have explicitly specified that the `1.0` is being assigned to `c`, so it cannot possibly be the value for `b`. The value for `b` has to fall back to it's default, `1`.